# Regex: inputs exactly 4 digits, check whether the inputted number appears in the first 10,000 characters

Tags: python, regex, while-loop

**Anyone can please check my code?**

When the user inputs exactly 4 digits, check whether the inputted number appears in the first 10,000 characters (after the decimal) of the text file(which name is "square root of 2.txt") and tell the user its position using .find() method.

Make a new file called inputted_number.txt. Modify the code so that all the valid input is saved in that file. The contents of that file should look something like this:

> 3210

> 3222

> 4771

**I don' know how to use re.find(), is that re.search? My codes below:**

```
#import my file 
    myfile = open("sqroot2_10kdigits.txt")
    txt = myfile.read()
    myfile.close()
    
# while True block use re.find
    
    while True:
        try: 
            number = str(input("Enter four digits: "))
            int(number)
            if re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d',txt)) == True:
                print(f'The digits {int(number} appear in the first 10,000 characters of the square root of 2.' )
                print(f'They appear starting on the {starting position}th character after the decimal.' )
      
            else :
                print(f'Sorry, the digits {int(number)} do not appear in the first 10,000 characters of the square root of 2.')
```

#NO.5 make a new file

```
    with open('inputted_number.txt.', 'w') as filehandle:
        filehandle.write('\n')
```

Anyone can check my code please!

Comment: It's `string.find(...)` (in your case `txt.find(number)`), not `re.find(...)`. Additionally, your line `int(number)` does not do anything useful.

Comment: but how to use .find() method, you may please modify my code directly. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

For what you are describing you do not need a regex.

```
txt = '2319871325876234897034589734527861' \
    '3098623409862349856243598672354897' \
    '2348776623534078459996505467097201'

while True:
    number = input("Enter four digits (q to quit): ")
    if number.lower() == 'q':
        break
    elif len(number) != 4 or not number.isdigit():
        print("Please enter four numbers")
        continue
    pos = txt.find(number)
    if pos > -1:
        print(
            f'The digits {number} appear in the first '
            '10,000 characters of the square root of 2.'
            f'They appear starting on the {pos}th '
            'character after the decimal.'
        )
    else:
        print(
            f'Sorry, the digits {number} do not appear '
            'in the first 10,000 characters of the '
            'square root of 2.'
        )
```

Among the changes:

- use str.find not a regex
- no need to cast the string as either a str or an int
- casting as an int will cause trouble with say 0001
- added some basic validation, length and digits

Comment: Thank you!!! You are the best! I try to add a break statement in this code.   elif number == 'q': break but errors happened....

Comment: you need to check for q first, as per edit.

Comment: Hey, if I want to make a new file called inputted_number.txt. I want to use this code so that all the valid input is saved in that file.  I try to use the codes: with open('inputted_number.txt.', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write('\n') #but it seems not work.... can you please give me some ideas? you are the best!!